# Identify destination of data which cause VALUE_ERROR in pl sql block

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, error-handling

my package is raising ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error.

Can I add some code in catch block to identify what data to which field are unsuccessfully inserted?

Right now I just have:

```
WHEN OTHERS
 ...log SQLCODE and SQLERRM...
 RAISE PROGRAM ERROR;
 RETURN;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the statement which raises the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the below quote as many times until you understand it completely.

> A when others is almost always a BUG unless it is immediately followed
>   by a RAISE.

- `WHEN OTHERS` **hides where the error comes from.**
- `WHEN OTHERS` **breaks the Atomicity of a procedure call**.

Remember, for errors, **`RAISE –> CATCH –> HANDLE`**

So, first remove all the exception handlers, and re-execute the PL/SQL block. The error stack will have the **correct line number** and other error details.

Read https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_test_others(i_val IN VARCHAR2) AS
2       o_val NUMBER;
3    BEGIN
4       SELECT i_val INTO o_val FROM dual;
5       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(o_val);
6    EXCEPTION
7       WHEN OTHERS THEN
8          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLCODE: '||SQLCODE);
9          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Message: '||SQLERRM);
10         RAISE;
11    END;
12    /
Procedure created

SQL>
SQL> BEGIN
2       p_test_others('a');
3    END;
4    /
SQLCODE: -6502
Message: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
BEGIN
p_test_others('a');
END;
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at "P_TEST_OTHERS", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Or else,

For logging the errors, use:

- **dbms_utility.format_error_stack**, and
- **dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace**

to get the call stack.

For example,

```
SQL> declare
  2    v1 integer := 1;
  3    v2 integer := 0;
  4    v3 integer;
  5    procedure p1 (v1 in integer, v2 in integer, v3 out integer) is 
  6    begin 
  7      v3 := v1 / v2;
  8    end;
  9    procedure p2 (v1 in integer, v2 in integer, v3 out integer) is 
 10    begin 
 11      p1 (v1, v2, v3);
 12    end;
 13  begin
 14    p2 (v1, v2, v3);
 15  exception
 16    when others then
 17      dbms_output.put_line ('---------------------');
 18      dbms_output.put_line ('This is what you record in log table:');
 19      dbms_output.put (dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
 20      dbms_output.put (dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
 21      dbms_output.put_line ('---------------------');
 22      raise;
 23  end;
 24  /
---------------------
This is what you record in log table:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at line 7
ORA-06512: at line 11
ORA-06512: at line 14
---------------------
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
ORA-06512: at line 22
```

**Update** Per OP's request

with exception block, the line number will go to the line number of the exception handler.

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    INSERT INTO t
  3      (A
  4      ) VALUES
  5      ('one'
  6      );
  7  EXCEPTION
  8  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  9    RAISE;
 10  END;
 11  /
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "LALIT"."T"."A" (actual: 3, maximum: 1)
ORA-06512: at line 9


SQL>
```

Without exception block, you have the correct line number where the error comes from:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    INSERT INTO t
  3      (A
  4      ) VALUES
  5      ('one'
  6      );
  7  END;
  8  /
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "LALIT"."T"."A" (actual: 3, maximum: 1)
ORA-06512: at line 2


SQL>
```

So, the error stack tells you the `schame`, `table_name`, `column_name` and other details like the maximum size allowed and the actual size.

For more specific or customized error logging, write your own code using all the required column names in the exception block to log the errors as and when they occur while inserting values in those columns.

Comment: If I am understaning these examples correctly, it gives me only line and error message. I am interested in what data is inserted where. For example if I try to insert "something" into field_name VARCHAR2(1), I want to know that: "error: "something" - field_name". Because inserts that are in package are opertating with hundreds of field, so simple line number won't help me.

Comment: Why not? You will definitely get the error with the complete details about the table_name, column_name, actual size, maximum size etc. See my update in the answer.

Comment: You get the error details only for a single `INSERT` or `UPDATE` but not for multiple records.

Comment: Yes, for multiple columns, it needs some lines of coding in the exception handler to include the column name, table name etc. . That's how we are supposed to log the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a situation like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (PK NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, COL_A NUMBER(2), COL_B NUMBER(2));

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    SELECT LEVEL AS PK, ROUND(100*DBMS_RANDOM.NORMAL) AS COL_A, ROUND(100*DBMS_RANDOM.NORMAL) AS COL_B
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 20;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
END;

ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Obviously you don't know neither the row nor the column which raised the error. One approach to find it out is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_TEMP AS
SELECT LEVEL AS PK, ROUND(100*DBMS_RANDOM.NORMAL) AS COL_A, ROUND(100*DBMS_RANDOM.NORMAL) AS COL_B
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 20;

DECLARE
sqlstr VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN

    FOR aRow IN (SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE_TEMP) LOOP
        INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (PK) VALUES (aRow.PK); 
        FOR aCol IN (SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE_TEMP') LOOP
        BEGIN
            sqlstr := 'UPDATE MY_TABLE a SET '||aCol.column_name||' = (SELECT '||aCol.column_name||' FROM MY_TABLE_TEMP b WHERE a.PK = b.PK) WHERE a.PK = :pk';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlstr USING aRow.PK;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Error at line '||aRow.PK||' for column '||aCol.column_name ||' -> '||SQLERRM);
        END;
        END LOOP;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Line '||aRow.PK||' -> OK');
    END LOOP;

END;

Line 1 -> OK
Line 2 -> OK
Error at line 3 for column COL_B -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 3 -> OK
Error at line 4 for column COL_A -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 4 -> OK
Error at line 5 for column COL_A -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 5 -> OK
Error at line 6 for column COL_A -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 6 -> OK
Error at line 7 for column COL_B -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 7 -> OK
Error at line 8 for column COL_A -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Error at line 8 for column COL_B -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 8 -> OK
Error at line 9 for column COL_A -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 9 -> OK
Error at line 10 for column COL_B -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 10 -> OK
Line 11 -> OK
Error at line 12 for column COL_B -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 12 -> OK
Line 13 -> OK
Line 14 -> OK
Line 15 -> OK
Line 16 -> OK
Error at line 17 for column COL_B -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 17 -> OK
Line 18 -> OK
Error at line 19 for column COL_A -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Error at line 19 for column COL_B -> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
Line 19 -> OK
```